# How to increase edittexts' number in for loop

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have 8 `EditText` and I want to check whether these `EditText`s are empty or not.
This is my code:

```java
if (edt1.getText().toString().equals("K")
      &&!edt2.getText().toString().equals("")
      &&!edt3.getText().toString().equals("")
      &&!edt4.getText().toString().equals("")
      &&!edt5.getText().toString().equals("")
      &&!edt6.getText().toString().equals("")
      &&!edt7.getText().toString().equals("")
      &&!edt8.getText().toString().equals("")){
    next();
}
```

This is what i want:

```java
int count=0;
for(int i=1;i<=8,i++){
    if(!edt.getText().toString().equals(""))//how can I increase the number of edt, if i=1, edt1 and if i=2, edt2... 
        count++;
}
if(count==8){
    next();
}
```

Comment: Put them in an array. Iterate the array.

Comment: Not worked for me. I forgot to say i check my `EditText` if button was clicked. if one of `EditText` is empty then it should not go to `next()`. @ElliottFrisch

Comment: `EditText[] edtArr = { edt1, edt2, edt3, edt4, edt5, edt6, edt7, edt8 };` then loop over the contents of `edtArr`. Note that `edt[0]` is `edt1`.

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the EditText by line by line in an array. That would be much simpler. Also, you can utilise the String Utils http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html to check empty string or you can go with the default null and empty string check.

Put the references like edt1,ed2,edt3 into an array and loop over it. That would work.

```
int count=0;
EditText edt[] = {edt1,edt2,edt3,edt4,edt5,edt6,edt7,edt8}
for(int i=0;i<=7,i++){
    if(edt[0].getText().toString().equals("K") || !edt[i].getText().toString().equals(""))
        count++;
}
if(count==8){
    next();
}
```

Comment: My code works but i want to short it and i want to know possible or not.

Comment: Put the references like edt1,ed2,edt3 into an array and loop over it. That would work

Comment: I tried like this [link](https://imgur.com/0X4iwWI) but i check my `EditText` if button was clicked. Some `EditText`s are empty the others are not.

Comment: You can write some like these. 
s[0].equals("K") || !s[i].equals("")